# Matrix product rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have a list of functions $f_1, ..., f_n$ where $f_i: \mathbb{R}^h \to \mathbb{R}^{n_i \times n_{i+1}}$ for $i \in \{1, ..., n-1\}$ and $f_n: \mathbb{R}^{n_n \times 1}$. Essentially, I have a product:

$\begin{align}
f_1 (\mathbf{x})f_2 (\mathbf{x})f_3 (\mathbf{x})...f_n (\mathbf{x})
\end{align}$

and I would like to take a derivative with respect to $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^h$. In other words, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} f_1 (\mathbf{x})f_2 (\mathbf{x})f_3 (\mathbf{x})...f_n (\mathbf{x})$. By calculus, I know that this should involve some product rule, but I am not sure how to express them, because each becomes a Tensor. Any insights would be greatful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the product of some matrices and a vector 
$$p = ABCy$$
Calculate the differential, then vectorize, then find the gradient with respect to $x$.
$$\eqalign{
dp &= ABC\,dy + AB\,dC\,y + A\,dB\,Cy + dA\,BCy \\
 &= ABC\,dy + (y^T\otimes AB)dc + (y^TC^T\otimes A)db + (y^TC^TB^T\otimes I)da \\
\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}
 &= ABC\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}
  + (y^T\otimes AB)\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}
  + (y^TC^T\otimes A)\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}
  + (y^TC^TB^T\otimes I)\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} \\
}$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product and $\;a={\rm vec}(A),\,b={\rm vec}(B),\,$etc.

The standard (column-stacking) vectorization formula is
$$\eqalign{
F &= ABC \\
{\rm vec}(F) &= (C^T\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(B) \\
f &= (C^T\otimes A)\,b \\
}$$